# Find checkbox and textbox placed inside gridview using javascript

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I want to get the value of check box placed inside grid view. if check box is checked, it textbox in that row should be enable and if it is again uncheked, the textbox should get clear and disabled. I asked this question few hours back but still didn't get satisfactory answer. 
I tried like this.

//My grid code.

```
<asp:GridView ID="DeptGrid" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptId" HeaderText="ID"/>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="DeptName" HeaderText="Department"/>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:CheckBox ID="addToCompanyBox"  onClick="EnableHODBox()" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Add
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:TemplateField>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:TextBox ID="hodNameBox" runat="server" Width="200px" Enabled="false"></asp:TextBox>
                        </ItemTemplate>
                        <HeaderTemplate>
                            Dept Head
                        </HeaderTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
```

//My javascript code

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 function EnableHODBox() {
     //alert('hello');
     var GridView = document.getElementById('<%=DeptGrid.ClientID %>');
     //var GridView = document.getElementById('');
     var DeptId;
     if (GridView.rows.length > 0) {
         for (Row = 1; Row < GridView.rows.length; Row++) {
            // DeptId = GridView.rows.cell[0];
             if (GridView.rows[Row].cell[3].type == "checkbox")
             // var chkbox = GridView.rows[Row].cell[3].type == "checkbox"
                 (GridView.rows[Row].cell[3].type).checked = true;
         }
     }
 }
 </script>
```

Comment: where u kept function, where u called it. paste Code is appreciated

Comment: Is your issue that you want to be able to find the corresponding textbox when the checkbox is ticked for a specific row?

Comment: I got the problem. Actually it needs to be called at "onclick" event.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `onclick` JavaScript instead of the `OncheckedChanged` event which is a CheckBox server side event.

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="CheckBox2" runat="server" onclick="Javascript:JSfunctionName();" />
```

**Edit:**

```
var GridView = document.getElementById('<%=DeptGrid.ClientID %>')
```

**Edit:** Upon your request in comment

```
 if (GridView.rows[Row].cell[2].type == "checkbox")
 {
    if (GridView.rows[Row].cell[2].childNodes[0].checked)
    {
       GridView.rows[Row].cell[3].childNodes[0].disabled=false;// Enable your control here
    }
 }
```

Comment: @Muhammad Akhtar...I can call my javascript by this method. But when I try to find gridview using  "var GridView = document.getElementById('DeptGrid')", then it shows null even though, the grid view is there on page

Comment: @Muhammad..Thanks dear...Your answers always works for me.But my actual problem is somewhat different.I divided my problem to small number of problems just to make it simpler.I have updated my question. Please have a look at it. I hope your answer will help me again...

Comment: @Muhammad..I tried like this before and this time again.It shows some error in if (GridView.rows[Row].cell[3].type == "checkbox") statement. Its not going inside if{} block

Comment: I have updated my answer again. It seems to be Cell index issue, I have updated Index issues.

Comment: @Muhammad...I tried this too, but when I kept watch, it shows error 'TypeError: GridView.rows[Row].cell is undefined'. I cant understand why it shows undefined in if{} block when it seems perfectly working in other part before it..

Answer (score 2):

This solution is ***tested*** and ***works*** using only `JavaScript` (no `jQuery` is required for this solution!).

### 1. C# Part (In `Page_Load` Method)

In `Page_Load` we need to add a small hack:

```
foreach(GridViewRow row in YourGridViewControlID.Rows)
{
    if (row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow )
    {
      ((CheckBox) row.FindControl("YourCheckBoxID")).Attributes.Add("onchange", "javascript:TextboxAutoEnableAndDisable(" + (row.RowIndex ) + ");");
    }
}
```

This way, we are adding the JavaScript function call on the `OnChange` event of every `CheckBox` of our `GridView`. What is special and we can't achieve through the `HTML` is that we are passing the `Row Index` of each one in the JavaScript function, something that we need later.

### 2. Some important notes for the HTML Part

Make sure that both `Checkbox` control and `Textbox` control but **more importantly** your `GridView` Control has static id by using the `ClientIDMode="Static"` as shown bellow:

```
<asp:CheckBox ID="YourCheckBoxID" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static"/>
<asp:TextBox ID="YourTextBoxID" TextMode="SingleLine" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />
```

And for the `GridView` control:

```
<asp:GridView ID="YourGridViewControlID" ...... ClientIDMode="Static" runat="server">
```

### 3. Javascript Part

And then in your JavaScript file/code:

```
function TextboxAutoEnableAndDisable(Row) {
  // Get current "active" row of the GridView.
  var GridView = document.getElementById('YourGridViewControlID');
  var currentGridViewRow = GridView.rows[Row + 1];

  // Get the two controls of our interest.
  var rowTextBox = currentGridViewRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
  var rowCheckbox = currentGridViewRow.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];

  // If the clicked checkbox is unchecked.
  if( rowCheckbox.checked === false) {
    // Empty textbox and make it disabled
    rowTextBox.value = "";
    rowTextBox.disabled = true;
    return;
  }

  // To be here means the row checkbox is checked, therefore make it enabled.
  rowTextBox.disabled = false;
}
```

### 4. Some Notes for the above implementation

- Note that in the JavaScript code, at the line:
  `var currentGridViewRow = GridView.rows[Row + 1];`
  the `[Row + 1]` is important to make this work and should not change.
- And finally:

The following lines:

```
var rowTextBox = currentGridViewRow.cells[2].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
var rowCheckbox = currentGridViewRow.cells[0].getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
```

The `.cells[2]` and `.cells[0]` is maybe different for you, so you have to choose the correct number in the `[]`.
Usually, this will be the column number of your `GridView` starting counting from `0`.

So if your `CheckBox` was in the first column of the GridView then you need `.cells[0]`.
If your `TextBox` is in the second column of your `GridView` then you need `.cells[1]` (in my case above, `TextBox` was in the third column of my `GridView` and therefore, I used `.cells[2]`)

Answer (score 0):

I also found that the statement if (GridView.rows[Row].cell[2].type == "checkbox") results in an error, GridView.rows[Row].cell[2].type is undefined.  The code I have running now is as follows:

```
    var grid = document.getElementById('<%=grdResults.ClientID%>');
    if (grid.rows.length > 0) {
        for (row = 1; row < grid.rows.length; row++) {
            if (grid.rows[row].cells[0].childNodes[0].checked) {
                // do something here
                alert('function for row ' + row);
            }                                  
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define your grid like this :

```
 <div>
   <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server"  Width = "550px"
    AutoGenerateColumns = "false" Font-Names = "Calibri" 
    Font-Size = "12pt" HeaderStyle-BackColor = "LightYellow" AllowPaging ="true"  ShowFooter = "true"  OnPageIndexChanging = "OnPaging" PageSize = "10" >
   <Columns>
      <asp:TemplateField ItemStyle-Width = "100px"  HeaderText = "Name">
        <ItemTemplate>
         <asp:TextBox ID="txtPeriod" runat="server" CssClass="css1 mycss" Text='<%# Eval("Period")%>' 
             onblur="SetPostingPeriod(this)"></asp:TextBox>
        </ItemTemplate>                       
    </asp:TemplateField>   
   </Columns> 
   <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#C2D69B"  />
</asp:GridView> 
</div>
```

And your Javascript Function Would be :

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
     /* Populating same data to all the textboxes inside grid, 
     once change of text for one textbox - by using jquery
     */
     function SetPostingPeriod(obj) {

         var cntNbr = $("#" + obj.id).val();
      // var cntNbr = document.getElementById(obj.id).value;
      // alert(cntNbr);

         //Access Grid element by using name selector
         $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> input[name*='txtPeriod']").each(function (index) {

             if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "")
                 if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
                     $(this).val(cntNbr);
                 }
         });
     }
 </script>
```

This Javascript function is called onblur event of the textbox. 
 When this function is called at the same time it passes a parameter 
 which is nothing but the textbox id.

Inside javascript function by using the parameter which is the 
id of the textbox we are getting the vaue.

Here is the code :

```
      var cntNbr = $("#" + obj.id).val();
```

Then For each of the "txtPeriod" controls available inside the grid, we need to assign 
 the value of current "txtPeriod" textbox value to them.

Looping Grid to identify each "txtPeriod" available :
   Here is the code :

```
 $("#<%=GridView1.ClientID %> input[name*='txtPeriod']").each(function (index) {

 });
```

Inside this loop we need to assign the "txtPeriod"(current/Modified) value to other 
    "txtPeriod" textboxes.Before assign its good practice to check is it null or NAN.
 Here is the code :

```
               if ($.trim($(this).val()) != "")
                 if (!isNaN($(this).val())) {
                     $(this).val(cntNbr);
                 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi here you are having very easy Solution

Suppose your grid is like this :

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" Height="64px"
    Width="389px" EnableViewState="False">
    <Columns>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="EmployeeId">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblEmployeeId" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="FirstName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblFirstName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
        <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="LastName">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <asp:Label ID="lblLastName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:Label>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </asp:TemplateField>
    </Columns>
    <HeaderStyle BackColor="#FF66FF" ForeColor="#660033" />
</asp:GridView>
```

and your javascript to find controls inside your grid is

```
   <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnAddToGrid").click(function () {
                var $grid = $('#<%=GridView1.ClientID %>');
                var $row = $grid.find('tr:last').clone().appendTo($grid);
                var employeeId = $row.find("span[id*='lblEmployeeId']").text();
                var firstname =  $row.find("span[id*='lblFirstName']").text();
                var lastname = $row.find("span[id*='lblLastName']").text();
              alert("ID :" + employeeId +"\n" + "Name :" + firstname +" "+ lastname );
            });
        });
    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Find controls inside the grid using java script:**

```
for (var r = 1; r < grid.rows.length; ++r) {

    var indexValue = 0; //based on browser. //IE8
    var txtPeriod= grid.rows[r].cells[2].childNodes[indexValue];
    if (typeof (txtPeriod.value) == "undefined")//IE9                      
        indexValue = 1
     var txtPeriod= grid.rows[r].cells[2].childNodes[indexValue];
     alert(txtPeriod.value);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var x = document.getElementById('<%=grdResults.ClientID%>').querySelectorAll("input");
var i;
var cnt = 0;
for (i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
     if(x[i].type== "checkbox" && x[i].checked)
     cnt++;
}
alert("item selected=" + cnt);
```

Comment: When answering a question format the code you're providing and explain what you are doing.